# File handling: Loop through text file and continually compare parameters

Tags: java, file, loops, text, parameters

I'm looping through text file and need to compare the contents of the text file to parameters being submitted by a user. The code I've written so far will only compare the last value in the text file.
Question: How would I continually loop and check the contents V parameters passed, stopping when there's a match between the two?

Here's what I have so far:

```
public boolean isAuthenticated(String username, String password) throws FileNotFoundException{
    boolean status = true;
    File file = new File("C:\\" "\\" "\\login.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

    List<Login> login = new ArrayList<Login>();

    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String [] details = line.split(":");
        String storedUsername = details[0];
        String storedPassword = details[1];
        Login l = new Login(username, password);

        if(storedUsername.equals(username)&& storedPassword.equals(password)){
            status = true;
        }else{
            status = false;
        }

    }
    return status;
}
```

Thanks! Query6273

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No this works fine, it only seems to compare the last value within the .txt though. I'm assuming it reads to the last value of the file then does the check.. should this work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does compare every line of the file to the username and password. But at each iteration, you replace the previous value of `status` with the status of the current line.

So you end up returning the status of the last line.

You need to break out of the loop as soon as you found the user you were looking for. For example:

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    ...

    if (storedUsername.equals(username) && storedPassword.equals(password)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

or

```
// we haven't found the user yet, so status is false
boolean status = false;

while (scan.hasNextLine() && !status) {
    ...

    if (storedUsername.equals(username) && storedPassword.equals(password)) {
        status = true;
    }
}
return status;
```

Note that the Scanner should be closed properly. You should use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).